# Nuxt Vanilla Site Body Attributes

Tags: nuxt.js

I've looked all over the documentation and I cannot find a hint anywhere.

I want to add some default attributes and classes to my `<body>` tag for all pages.

Where can I set these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add attributes and classes to the `body` tag using [the head method](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-head) and `bodyAttrs`.

An example of using the head method:

```
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'test-class',
        'data-test': 'some-attribute-data',
      }
    }
  },
}
```

[image]

If you want to add it to all the pages, include the code in your layout.